# SQLITE не выводит определенные данные

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

Есть база данных SQLITE в ней ряд полей, в том числе дата и время, в приложении WPF я пишу запрос по которому на странице с историей операций должны выводится данные из таблицы SQLite.
В целом все работает, но почему то выводятся все данные кроме определенной даты, а именно сегодняшней 12.09, при этом выводятся данные по любой другой сортировке.. все операции за месяц или за определенный день, но именно за этот день не выводятся, даже если изменить в БД последнюю операцию за 12.09 и прописать ей дату 12.08 то в операциях за август её нет.. такое ощущение что, начиная с операций от 12.09 не по дате а по фактическому месту в БД эти операции почему не видны для команд.. есть идеи ?

```
string sMonth = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM"); //узнаем текущий месяц
var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=B.Zanachka.db");
connection.Open();
SqliteCommand command = new SqliteCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM Moneys WHERE Дата_Время LIKE '___{sMonth}______________' ORDER BY id DESC"; //при открытии окна историй операций, изначально видим операции за весь текущий месяц
            
ListHistory.ItemsSource = command.ExecuteReader();
```

[image: Итоговый вывод данных + БД]

Comment: *в приложении WPF .. выводятся все данные кроме определенной даты, а именно сегодняшней* А если не пользоваться приложением? если использовать другой клиент? *при этом выводятся данные по любой другой сортировке* А при чём тут вообще сортировка?

Comment: Может как-то так лучше: `Дата_Время LIKE '%.{sMonth}.%` всё-равно у вас точки по бокам только у месяца могут быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать вот такой шаблон поиска, поскольку точки с обеих сторон у вас только у месяца встречаются:

```
WHERE Дата_Время LIKE '%.{sMonth}.%'
```

Вы привязываетесь к конкретному числу позиций в дате, а это не всегда может быть корректно - см. ответ Lem0nti.

Но в целом это какой-то кривой способ, всё-таки корректнее хранить данные именно в виде поля типа дата-время, брать из неё нужный компонент - месяц - и именно его сравнивать с нужным, а не искать в строке.

Comment: в sqlite же нет полей с типом дата/время, только text / integer / blob / real / numeric, по этому и храню в виде текста

Comment: А, понятно, ну я возможности `sqlite` наизусть не помню )

Answer (score 2):

`'___{sMonth}______________'`

здесь требование иметь 14 знаков после месяца, а транзакции за утро 12-го числа имеют только 13. Сделайте, чтобы время сохранялось с предваряющим нулём для одноциферного значения и всё заработает как надо.

Answer (score 1):

В sqlite нет типа `DateTime`, но есть мощный набор функций для работы с датой и временем: [Date And Time Functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).
Чтобы их использовать, вам нужно перейти на формат ISO-8601. Это даст возможность не только использовать эти функции, но и массу других достоинств. В частности, сортировка по дате станет элементарной.

Когда сохраняете значение типа дата-время в БД, используйте формат `s`:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("s")
```

Это так называемый sortable (сортируемый) формат, соответствующий стандарту ISO-8601. Значения в БД будут выглядеть так: `2022-09-10T15:23:11`.

Теперь при поиске данных в БД можно использовать функции sqlite.

```
string month = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");

var sql = $"SELECT * FROM [Moneys] WHERE strftime('%m', Дата_Время) = @month ORDER BY id DESC;";

using var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=test.db");
connection.Open();

using var command = new SqliteCommand(sql, connection);
command.Parameters.Add("month", SqliteType.Text).Value = month;

ListHistory.ItemsSource = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Обратите внимание на `using` - это автоматически освободит ресурсы, даже в случае исключения.
Обратите внимание на применение параметризованного запроса - это увеличит производительность, т. к. в кэше БД будет храниться только один план запроса.